# Getting incorrect answers when computing $\int_{0}^a \frac{\cos(\pi n x/a)}{x^2+a^2}\ \! \mathrm dx$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, solution-verification, change-of-variable

Please do not try to close this question. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133637/an-integral-int-aa-frac-cos-pi-n-x-ax2a2-mathrm-dx) doesn't have the answer I want.

I found this integral in a book (I forgot the name).

$$\int_{0}^a \dfrac{\cos(\pi n x/a)}{x^2+a^2}\ \! \mathrm dx $$

Where $a>0$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z^+}$.

I tried differentiating under the integral sign w.r.t. $n$ and preparing a differential equation, but here is the problem.

Let's prepare differential equation from the raw form.
$$I(n)=\int_0^a \dfrac{\cos(\pi n x /a)}{x^2+a^2}\ \! \mathrm dx $$
Differentiating both sides twice w.r.t. $n$,
$$\begin{align}  \dfrac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm d n^2}I(n)&=-\dfrac{\pi^2}{a^2}\int_0^a \dfrac{x^2\cos(\pi n x/a)}{x^2+a^2}\ \! \mathrm dx  \\ &= -\dfrac{\pi^2}{a^2}\int_0^a \cos(\pi n x /a) \ \! \mathrm dx +\pi^2 \int_0^a \dfrac{\cos(\pi n x /a)}{x^2+a^2}\ \! \mathrm dx \\ &= -\dfrac{\pi}{an}\sin(\pi n )+\pi^2I(n)\end{align}$$
As we know, $\sin(n\pi)=0 \ , n\in \mathbb{Z}$, so we end up with

$$\dfrac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm d n^2}I(n)=\pi^2I(n)$$

Now, let's start with the substitution $x=at$.
$$I(n)=\dfrac{1}{a}\int_0^1 \dfrac{\cos(\pi n t)}{t^2+1}\ \! \mathrm dt$$
Again differentiating twice w.r.t. $n$,
$$\begin{align} \dfrac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm d n^2}I(n) &=-\dfrac{\pi^2}{a}\int_0^1 \dfrac{t^2\cos(\pi n t)}{t^2+1}\ \! \mathrm dt \\ &=-\dfrac{\pi^2}{a}\int_0^1 \cos(\pi n t)\ \! \mathrm dt+\dfrac{\pi^2}{a}\int_0^1 \dfrac{\cos(\pi n t)}{t^2+1}\ \! \mathrm dt \\ &= -\dfrac{\pi}{an}\sin(\pi n)+\pi^2I(n) \\ \dfrac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm d n^2}I(n)&=\pi^2I(n)\end{align}$$

In both the cases, the results are the same. But they don't work for different values of $a$ and $n$. How can I do this integral using the method I displayed?

As the comments have suggested we have to reconsider the domain of $n$, and solve the integral for $n \in \mathbb{R}$.
In that case, the differential equation will be
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dn^2}I(n)=\pi^2I(n)-\dfrac{\pi}{an}\sin(\pi n)$$
We have to solve this differential equation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An integral : $\int_{-a}^a \frac{\cos(\pi n x/a)}{x^2+a^2}\mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133637/an-integral-int-aa-frac-cos-pi-n-x-ax2a2-mathrm-dx)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124988/discussion-on-question-by-laxmi-narayan-bhandari-getting-incorrect-answers-when).

Comment: @Ricardo, I think I would be able to continue further. Thanks.